# text mining within same sentence in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a text file

> "I am writing today. Today I am thinking of writing. Today is great day"

I am trying to find number of instances within a sentence where "writing today" was mentioned.It can happen that "writing today" is not together but still part of same sentence (eg: 2nd sentence), need to capture that as well.

So in the above example, my count will be 2.

Any idea how to do it in R?
TIA

Comment: can't you use a regex ?
((\bwriting\b.*\btoday\b)|(\btoday\b.*\bwriting\b))

Comment: I am new wrt regex. Will it search only within sentence?

Comment: Since I am can text like "Today is great day. Writing is my hobby". With this example, the count should be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but with tidytext,

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

data_frame(text = "I am writing today. Today I am thinking of writing. Today is great day") %>%
    unnest_tokens(sentence, text, 'sentences', to_lower = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(sentence_number = row_number()) %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, sentence, 'words', drop = FALSE) %>%
    group_by(sentence_number) %>% 
    filter('today' %in% word, 'writing' %in% word) %>% 
    select(-word) %>% distinct() %>% ungroup() %>%
    mutate(count = n())

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>                          sentence sentence_number count
#>                             <chr>           <int> <int>
#> 1             I am writing today.               1     2
#> 2 Today I am thinking of writing.               2     2
```

Comment: Awesome... So, I just need to take last row to get the count of Occurrences... Thanks.

Comment: If you _just_ want the count, you can replace everything after `filter` with `ungroup() %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(sentence_number))`